# How to add logo to WordPress template in this example?

Tags: wordpress

I have an issues with editing materialize template on WordPress.

I want to change the top part of the template to use my picture as responsive...The web page in installing to is: 
testiram.mywebcommunity.org/

The picture i want to use is:
[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHzdZ.png)

I want to use it to be viewed in the are shown below and around it i want my default background theme...but whatever i change i don' get the result..

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qx4uz.png)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look on the developer Tools, you can see

`http://testiram.mywebcommunity.org/wp-content/themes/materialize/media/_frontend/img/logotip.png
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Make sure the path is right.

Comment: My God. It was becouse of logotip.png instead of logotip.PNG 

Thank you very much!